# Count number of element in a array that is less than the element in another array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I am not sure whether this is the right place to ask this question, but I am struggling to get to the right answer myself. I have done a programming test and I can not figure why my code fails in certain test cases.

The problem is that given an unsorted array of elements, e.g [1, 4, 2, 4] and an array of maximum, e.g [3,5], gives the solution of the count of elements in the first array that is less than the maximums in the second array. i.e [2, 4]

some example would be

inputs

```
nums = [2, 10, 5, 4, 8]
maxes = [3, 1, 7, 8]
```

outputs

```
solution = [1, 0, 3, 4]
```

inputs

```
nums = [1, 4, 2, 4]
maxes = [3, 5]
```

outputs

```
solution = [2, 4]
```

since there is one element is that is less than or equal to 3, and 0 element that is less than or equal to 1 and 3 element  that is less than or equal to 3 and 4 element that is less than or equal to 8

Comment: Why is 1 not included its count is less than the items in max array, it seems no different than 2

Comment: Shouldn't the first `solution` be `[1, 0, 3, 3]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudocode:

```
Sort number array
Sort maximum array
create a list counts
for max elem in max array
      find first elem in number array that is greater than or 
      equal to max elem and save its (index+1) in counts
```

So now counts will be a parallel array to the sorted number array.  At index 0 of counts we have the number of elements smaller than the number at index 0 of max array.

You can do the below if you need your data in a dictionary form (as you did in your solution) as opposed to two parallel lists.

```
Set index to 0
for max elem in max array:
    dictionary[max elem] = counts[index]
    index += 1
```

Note you can use enumerate above but I wasn't sure you knew about it yet so I tried to give the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified version of what you need to do

```
nums = [1, 4, 2, 4]
maxes = [3,5]

result = [0]*len(maxes)
for index, max_val in enumerate(maxes):
    for num in nums:
        if num <= max_val:
            result[index] += 1

print(result)
```

Comment: algorithmically it is not very efficient at all comparing with the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

I'd just write this as

```
[sum(1 for x in nums if x < m) for m in maxes]
```

Demo:

```
>>> nums = [2, 10, 5, 4, 8]
>>> maxes = [3, 1, 7, 8]
>>> 
>>> [sum(1 for x in nums if x < m) for m in maxes]
[1, 0, 3, 3]
>>>    
>>> nums = [1, 4, 2, 4]
>>> maxes = [3, 5]
>>> 
>>> [sum(1 for x in nums if x < m) for m in maxes]
[2, 4]
```

It's readable, memory efficient, uses fast comprehensions implemented in C and you would have to work hard to find an example where further microoptimizations are justified.

Comment: algorithmically it is not very efficient at all comparing with the accepted answer

Comment: @Tomchan I encourage you to time the implementations. The overhead of the sorting, the traditional `for` loop and `__setitem__` calls have to be taken into account. In addition, "find first elem in number array that..." in the accepted solution is a linear scan inside the body of the outer `for` loop and therefore has quadratic complexity as well.

Comment: In the accepted answer, it sorted the array. So if you think about how the solution work, it basically says, I have a counter starting on the sorted number array and I check the first element of max and if it is less than or equal to, otherwise you increase the counter on the max array. So you actually go through the list once

Comment: whereas your answer, it scans the whole array again for each max in the max list regardless of the previous work done, because you didn't sort the array. So no better how efficient your implementation is, algorithmically it is inferior. That means if I can put the time and effort, I can come up with an implementation much better than yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_total_matches(team_a, team_b):
    if not team_b:
        return []
    if not team_a:
        return [0]*len(team_b)
    team_a.sort()
    team_b_sorted = sorted(team_b)
    a_i = 0
    b_i = 0
    c_sum = 0
    cnt = dict()
    while a_i <len(team_a) and b_i < len(team_b_sorted):
        val= team_b_sorted [b_i]
        if val not in cnt:
            while a_i < len(team_a) and val >= team_a[a_i]:
                c_sum += 1
                a_i += 1
            cnt[val] = c_sum
        b_i += 1
    result = []
    for val in team_b:
        result.append(cnt[val])

    return result
```